# Running into issues with importing multiple CSV's into different collections using Keen's Command Line Interface

Tags: keen-io

I have no problem importing one CSV file into a collection by using the keen-cli command

```
keen events:add -p xxxxxx -k xxxxxx -w xxxxxx -r xxxxxx --collection xxxxx --file xxxxxx.csv --csv
```

With `-p, -k, -w, -r` being key overrides to avoid installing `dotenv` and having to mess with an `.env` file.

This import works fine the first time until I try to repeat this with a different file and a different collection. By goal is to be able to compare both collections so I want to keep them in the same project but I always get the following error.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/keen-cli-0.2.3/lib/keen-cli.rb:16:in `deep_merge': undefined method `keys' for "15:53:30":String (NoMethodError)
```

I know Keen allows for multiple collections in the same project so I'm not 100% sure what's going on here.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data that is stored in your CSV? Specifically I'd be interested in any fields containing "15:53:30"

Comment: @jwegner couldn't find any instance of 15:53:30 , why would that cause an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Keen assumes that whatever your first column is will act as your unique key for the collection.

If there is any missing values in that list the entire thing fails.

Answer (score 0):

If one file is working and a seemingly identical file isn't working, try inspecting the not-working file for:

- misc or missing spaces, commas, and carriage returns at the end of the text
- misc or missing spaces, commas, and carriage returns at the end of lines